# Row sticking out of body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Oh boy, this issue is driving me nuts.

```html
<html lang="en-US" class="js">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">
 </head>

 <body class="">
  <div class="">
    
   <div id="" class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        Test
       </div>
   </div>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, the row in the body tag is sticking out and allow users to scroll to the right. I tried deleting all the stylesheets thinking something is breaking the layout, removing ids and classes to make sure nothing is affecting the style, and opening it with other browsers to see if my chrome is to blame... but no to all of my wild guesses!

Is it a glitch from 4.1.3 version or am I missing something very simple here??

Comment: I used Bootstrap a lot to build sites... but never seen this before :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `container`:

```html
<html lang="en-US" class="js">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">
 </head>

 <body class="">
  <div class="container">
    
   <div id="" class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        Test
       </div>
   </div>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can also use `container-fluid` for full-width.

See the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

Comment: Oh wait... Is it a must?

Comment: Dannnggg... looks like it's a must thing. How the heck didn't I know about this before... I will try it. Thanks!